# Redirect after dompdf didn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Recently I'd tried with a dompdf. But after converting my file to pdf `$this->event_registration();`is not working. How can I deal with this issue . ?

My code:

```
$data['info'] = $this->reg_model->getInfo();
        $id = $data['info']->id;
        $file = $data['info']->Register_num;
        $data['ed_info'] = $this->reg_model->getEdInfo($id);
        $this->load->view('info.html',$data);
        $html = $this->output->get_output();        
        // Load library
        $this->load->library('dompdf_generate');
        // Convert to PDF
        $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
        $this->dompdf->render();
        $this->dompdf->stream($file.".pdf");
        $this->event_registration();
```

Comment: check manually there would be not any bug above this function using die function..

Comment: Does `$this->event_registration()` write a location header to redirect the user?

Comment: I'am just  loading a view page there..